# Possible to build and run Docker images in Linux VM on Parallels on OS X?

Tags: macos, ubuntu, docker, parallels, lxc

I'm just getting started with Docker and use a MacBook Pro for development work.  I see the Docker instructions recommend using Virtual Box and Boot2Docker in this environment.  Anyone know if it would also work in a Linux VM in Parallels?

Comment: PS - I ask because I'm already trying this and getting lots of errors even with the tutorial images and "trusted" images in index.docker.io, so wondering if others have tried this setup too and got it to work or found it problematic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can totally run Docker in another kind of Linux VM.

If you already have some kind of Linux VM running, just check [Docker installation instructions](https://www.docker.io/gettingstarted/) for the distro installed in the Linux VM.

If you don't have a Linux VM, or if you don't want to touch your existing Linux VM, you can also download [boot2docker](https://github.com/steeve/boot2docker), and when creating the new VM, just attach the boot2docker image as a virtual CD-ROM image *or* a virtual hard disk image (yes, it actually supports both).